# Google JavaScript CAPTCHA handling

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Google API's to provide maps on a web page, however, Google frequently prompts for a CAPTCHA (I only know this from going into Firebug, users just get a JavaScript error) for requests for its javascript API's (e.g. http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?file=api&v=2&key=xxxx). However, this prevents visitors from our network (a very large (UK wide) WAN) using Google Maps etc from using these sites with it on. This is likely due to the fact the IP is shared by many people, so Google sees it as spam.

I don't see any way of contacting Google about this, so was wondering if there is any way of intercepting these failing JavaScript requests since they return a 403 status code? Perhaps by opening a new window, although that would not be user friendly (they will see the JavaScript after the CAPTCHA, so would be a cause of confusion and would need to refresh the page in question).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the right format in your request:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=YOUR_KEY
```

I don't know if it matters whether you're linking to google.com or google.co.uk.

**Update:** You could try contacting Google [here](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/request.py?contact_type=ban).

Comment: Nothing wrong with the request, just the fact pages don't work as I get a 403 error from Google, in HTML format rather than JavaScript. It is the same http://www.google.com/sorry/?.... page that you can sometimes get when doing searches.

Comment: Been such a long time since I first started seeing the error (form requires a start date).. plus it only happens occasionally and not entirely sure of the range.